# Textures won't work on some objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I am working on a scene, and am on UV mapping and texturing phase. I have managed to successfully UV map and texture a few objects, but for some weird reason now the objects I am trying to UV map won't take textures. In 3dview and render they are appearing pink, which I know means Blender isn't finding the textures, but I am browsing to select the texture images. The images are there. In one computer, after browsing to select the image, the node fails to show the name of the texture. On another computer, the name shows up but the texture doesn't get applied (same .blender file). Any ideas? I am using cycles render.

Comment: Try to see if your textures appear in the UV/Image editor. If not,they are not in Blender memory, so try to reload them (Alt+R) or reopen the files

Comment: are you using this file across different computers? if so, the file paths to the textures will be different and not work.

Comment: For future reference it is advised to always create a main parent folder for your project and place textures and all needed assets in a sub folder along with your .blend file. Blender by default tries to use relative paths, so when moving computers or changing the file path the images will still work the the sub-folder structure is maintained.

Answer (score -2):

I have seen something similar when I have forgotten to UVMap an object to which I intend to apply an image texture.

Comment: Please be more factual in your answer. An object will not appear in pink if there is no uv map but only to indicate a missing texture.

Comment: I was trying to be helpful - but admittedly with some uncertainty. I'll check the exact behaviour next time my work takes me that way.
New here.